# Trying to get a keyboard.next() for ENUM type

Tags: java, enums

Hey im getting the user to input details of a flight.  My plane type is an ENUM.

```
public enum AIRPLANETYPE
    {
        AIRBUS("1"), CORPORATE("2"), PRIVATE("3");

        private String planeName;

        private AIRPLANETYPE(String planeName)
        {
            this.planeName = planeName;
        }
    }

Flight.AIRPLANETYPE planeType = keyboard-------What goes in here.();
```

I cant figure out how to use the enum with the Scanner object.

Can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
AIRPLANETYPE airplaneType = AIRPLANETYPE.valueOf(keyboard.next());
```

Comment: That uses an import,  Ive an error on the import says the import Flight cannot be resolved.

Comment: You can remove the `Flight` if the enum is not an inner enum in a class of that name.

Comment: in this case it is.  I have it in my flight class.

Comment: Better to import it `import com.acme.etc.Flight.AIRPLANETYPE;` rather then using `Flight.AIRPLANETYPE airplaneType = Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.valueOf(keyboard.next());`